# Check if form's icon is nothing or set to the default one?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

Any idea how can I check if form's icon value is nothing or set to the default one? I tried something like this but with no luck...

```
If Me.Icon Is Nothing Then
     MsgBox("Nothing")
End If
```

I noticed that form's icon property has already a value. The default one. So, how can I check if my form uses this default value?

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: There's value in this question either way, but may I ask what you're trying to achieve? Or what you're trying to avoid doing?

Comment: @AFriend: I am making a custom form class and in one of it's properties I want to check if form already has an icon assigned or not and then add my code...

Comment: By reflection, `[Icon].GetType().GetField("iconData").GetValue([Icon])` (Instance, Non-Public). It's an array of bytes. You could confront it with the content of another icon. But, is something changing your forms' icons without your knowledge :)?

Comment: I posted the previous comment before a I could see yours. I mean, compare the byte array values to the default icon bytes. They're always the same.

Comment: @SimonetosTheGreek: no need to compare bytes, you can simply compare references. Look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50349140/284240)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there is no way to determine if the current `Icon` is the `DefaultIcon`. But there is a [static/shared property `DefaultIcon`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,bb1ad38e0038ef7b,references) which you could access via reflection:

```
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module FormsExtensions

    <Extension()>
    Public Function HasDefaultIcon(form As System.Windows.Forms.Form) As Boolean
        ' relies on reflection, so might break in future
        ' necessary because the DefaultIcon property is internal
        Dim fType = GetType(Windows.Forms.Form)
        Dim defaultIconProp = fType.GetProperty("DefaultIcon", BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Static)
        Dim defaultIcon = TryCast(defaultIconProp?.GetValue(form), System.Drawing.Icon)
        Return form.Icon Is defaultIcon
    End Function

End Module
```

With this extension method the check is easy:

```
Dim hasDefaultIcon As Boolean = Me.HasDefaultIcon()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer my friend!!! But how can I use this into an `IF` statement? Like this for example `If Me.HasDefaultIcon() Then`?

Comment: @SimonetosTheGreek: i don't understand your question. `If Me.HasDefaultIcon() Then MsgBox("Nothing")`

Comment: OK it is working... It was my fault. I had placed it in wrong "place". :)